# Stop MutationOberserver on click event

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I have a dynamic DOM structure where nodes get inserted and deleted all the time, in order to react to new nodes I'm using a MutationObserver that gets activated when the user clicks on a Button. The MutationObserver will run two functions everytime the user clicks on that button and the functions will keep running when the DOM structure I'm observing change.

What I'm trying to do is to disconnnect the MutationObservers as soon as the user clicks the button again (Let's say click first time then sort elements, click again and stop sorting elements). I'm passing a boolean (goSortDom) everytime the user clicks the button (if true go do stuff and observe, if false stop observing). The thing is when I try to disconnect the observers when goSortDom=false they will never get disconnected and the functions will keep running.

I'm pretty new to mutationObservers so I don't know if my approach is a bad practice that's why I will really appreciate commnents on that too.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Function 1: Assign Priorities
  function assignChatPriority(arrayParent) {
     //Assign Priorities
     //Observe if time change, if change re-assign priority to dom node
     timeInQueueDomObserver.observe(
     $(incomingChat).find(".time_cell")[0],
     configtimeInQueue
  }

  // Function 2: Reorder DOM
  function orderIncomingChats() {
    //Reorder DOM save DOM elements to Array
    //Replace original DOM with new sorted DOM 
  }

  //Declaring DOM Observers for Time in Queue and DOM container dynamics
  var incomingChatsDomObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
          if (
            mutation.addedNodes[i].attributes["data-priority"] === undefined
          ) {
            runExtensionFunctions();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
  var timeInQueueDomObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      if (
        mutation.addedNodes.length === 1 &&
        mutation.addedNodes[0].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE &&
        mutation.removedNodes.length === 1 &&
        mutation.removedNodes[0].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
      ) {
        runExtensionFunctions();
      }
    });
  });

  //Obervers Configuration
  let configChatsContainer = {
    childList: true,
  };
  let configtimeInQueue = {
    childList: true,
  };
  if (goSortDom) {
    //boolean is true go ahead run functions and observe
    assignChatPriority(incomingChatsRows);
    orderIncomingChats();
    incomingChatsDomObserver.observe(
      incomingChatsContainer[0],
      configChatsContainer
    );
  } else {
    //disconnect observers: WON'T WORK
    incomingChatsDomObserver.disconnect();
    timeInQueueDomObserver.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize and work on the MutationObserver's `incomingChatsDomObserver` and `timeInQueueDomObserver` within this function passed to .ready(). I don't see an outside reference. If that is the case, the `if (goSortDom)` will only be evaluated once for the initialized MutationObserver's. After that, the function ends and the references are lost. Calling the function again creates *new* MutationObserver's and the disconnect() calls will reference those new MutationObserver's instead of the already observing old ones!

Could it be that what you want to achieve is to move the initialization and reference of the MutationObserver's outside of this function and use it there? Or maybe disconnect the MutationObservers within theirselfs?

Let me give this a try. Since this is no full code, I cannot test it myself:

1. idea (move references):

```
// ANSWERER: Now the references are outside the ready function. If the ready function is done, this references still exist. 
  //Declaring DOM Observers for Time in Queue and DOM container dynamics
  var incomingChatsDomObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
          if (
            mutation.addedNodes[i].attributes["data-priority"] === undefined
          ) {
            runExtensionFunctions();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
  var timeInQueueDomObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      if (
        mutation.addedNodes.length === 1 &&
        mutation.addedNodes[0].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE &&
        mutation.removedNodes.length === 1 &&
        mutation.removedNodes[0].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
      ) {
        runExtensionFunctions();
      }
    });
  });

// ANSWERER: This is now possible  
function disconnectObservers() {
    incomingChatsDomObserver.disconnect();
    timeInQueueDomObserver.disconnect();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  // Function 1: Assign Priorities
  function assignChatPriority(arrayParent) {
     //Assign Priorities
     //Observe if time change, if change re-assign priority to dom node
     timeInQueueDomObserver.observe(
     $(incomingChat).find(".time_cell")[0],
     configtimeInQueue
  }

  // Function 2: Reorder DOM
  function orderIncomingChats() {
    //Reorder DOM save DOM elements to Array
    //Replace original DOM with new sorted DOM 
  }


  //Obervers Configuration
  let configChatsContainer = {
    childList: true,
  };
  let configtimeInQueue = {
    childList: true,
  };
  if (goSortDom) {
    //boolean is true go ahead run functions and observe
    assignChatPriority(incomingChatsRows);
    orderIncomingChats();
    incomingChatsDomObserver.observe(
      incomingChatsContainer[0],
      configChatsContainer
    );
  } else {
    //disconnect observers: WON'T WORK
    incomingChatsDomObserver.disconnect();
    timeInQueueDomObserver.disconnect();
  }
}
```

2. Version. MutationObserver's disconnect theirselfs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Function 1: Assign Priorities
  function assignChatPriority(arrayParent) {
     //Assign Priorities
     //Observe if time change, if change re-assign priority to dom node
     timeInQueueDomObserver.observe(
     $(incomingChat).find(".time_cell")[0],
     configtimeInQueue
  }

  // Function 2: Reorder DOM
  function orderIncomingChats() {
    //Reorder DOM save DOM elements to Array
    //Replace original DOM with new sorted DOM 
  }

  //Declaring DOM Observers for Time in Queue and DOM container dynamics
  var incomingChatsDomObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
          if (
            mutation.addedNodes[i].attributes["data-priority"] === undefined
          ) {
            runExtensionFunctions();
          }
        }
      }
    });
    // ANSWERER: Now the observer disconnects itself after the run. Remember: MutationObserver's disconnect itself from *everywhere*
    incomingChatsDomObserver.disconnect();
  });
  var timeInQueueDomObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      if (
        mutation.addedNodes.length === 1 &&
        mutation.addedNodes[0].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE &&
        mutation.removedNodes.length === 1 &&
        mutation.removedNodes[0].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
      ) {
        runExtensionFunctions();
      }
    });
    // ANSWERER: Now the observer disconnects itself after the run. Remember: MutationObserver's disconnect itself from *everywhere*
    timeInQueueDomObserver.disconnect();
  });

  //Obervers Configuration
  let configChatsContainer = {
    childList: true,
  };
  let configtimeInQueue = {
    childList: true,
  };
  if (goSortDom) {
    //boolean is true go ahead run functions and observe
    assignChatPriority(incomingChatsRows);
    orderIncomingChats();
    incomingChatsDomObserver.observe(
      incomingChatsContainer[0],
      configChatsContainer
    );
  } else {
    //disconnect observers: WON'T WORK
    incomingChatsDomObserver.disconnect();
    timeInQueueDomObserver.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, look at following. The MutationObserver's are bound to the button object, so clicking the button always references the once initialized MutationObserver's. That way they can be disconnected and reconnected (Try changing div#changes in a browser):

```
<html>
<body>
    <button id="somebutton">bla</button>
    <div id="changes"></div>
    <script>
        document.querySelector("#somebutton").addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (!this.incomingChatsDomObserver) {
                this.incomingChatsDomObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                    console.log("incomingChatsDomObserver", mutations);
                });
            }

            if (!this.timeInQueueDomObserver) {
                this.timeInQueueDomObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                    console.log("timeInQueueDomObserver", mutations);
                });
            }

            if (this.observing) {
                this.observing = false;
                this.incomingChatsDomObserver.disconnect();
                this.timeInQueueDomObserver.disconnect();
                this.innerText = "inactive";
            } else {
                this.observing = true;
                const changingDiv = document.querySelector("#changes");
                this.incomingChatsDomObserver.observe(changingDiv, { attributes: true });
                this.timeInQueueDomObserver.observe(changingDiv, { attributes: true });
                this.innerText = "active";
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Benno. The first option is not working because the mutation observer calls a function that has to be declared inside the document ready function (long story short I have to wait for the whole DOM to load then do things inside that function). The second option is not working too. I don't really know why but the DOM changes inside assignChatPriority just take place when a new dom element enters the structure. Your third suggestion is confusing to me, sorry.

Comment: All comes down to this: If your snippet is real code, the whole .ready() function will only run once, which means the if(goSortDom) is only run once and the MutationObserver's objects are only initialized once.

Lets focus on incomingChatsDomObserver. It is initialized *once* and then *either* called with .observe() *or* .disconnect(). After that, the reference is lost, so it will never observe if it got disconnected or disconnect if its observing.

I'm pretty sure your problem boils down to this.

Comment: Thank you @Benno, Your answers and in-depth explanation have helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to not be recognizing the (goSortDom) click event. Have you tried adding that code string to your to the button click event?
Vue.js Framework may be a great fit for your requirements. Other than that all I can tell you is the same thing you know.  Javascript acts very strangely when dom elements get changed dynamically.  I had an app that had an exponential number of selections that were loaded based on previous selections. Every time new information was loaded I had to be particular about the selectors used to manipulate data.  Otherwise, regardless of the Id or class selector, the JS would not function with newly imported data. I also had to use the .on( events [, selector ] [, data ] ) Javascript function instead of the .click() jquery function to get the work done. Specifically ensuring the selector information was filled out. 
`$("#myDiv").on('click', '.MyDivClass', function(){'Select All  and return information'};`

Comment: Thanks Matt but unfortunately Vue is not an option since I'm working with an already developed platform. Besides that I'm pretty sure there's a still a way to accomplish what I'm looking for just using javascript / JQuery but as i said before I'm new to mutationObservers so still trying to figure them out completely.